# update a given array with values from a set of objects php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to set the values of an empty array with another array (based on rows returned from a database).

I have tried a few things like `array_merge` but I just end up adding to the first array.

Just curious if there is a way to do this or would I need to iterate thought each array and merge them?

The second array can have between 1 and 3 arrays in it, while the first (the *"empty"*) array has 3 elements always.

```
Empty array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [quote_id] => 
            ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [quote_id] => 
            ...
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [quote_id] => 
            ...
        )

)
```

Array I want to copy data from

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [quote_id] => 1
            ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quote_id] => 1
            ...
        )

)
```

What I want to achieve

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [quote_id] => 1
            ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quote_id] => 1
            ...
        )

      [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [quote_id] => 
            ...
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [array union operator<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$combined = $rows + $empty;
```

> The **+** operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for explaining something I was curious about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php), but you'll have to be very careful with the keys, see the example in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$empty = array(
"0" => Array("id" => null,"quote_id" => null,"position" => null,"type" => null,"number" => null,"cost" => null,"total" => null),
"1" => Array("id" => null,"quote_id" => null,"position" => null,"type" => null,"number" => null,"cost" => null,"total" => null),
"2" => Array("id" => null,"quote_id" => null,"position" => null,"type" => null,"number" => null,"cost" => null,"total" => null))

;

$content = Array(
"0" => Array("id" => 1,"quote_id" => 1,"position" => 1,"type" => "dwdwdw","number" => 22,"cost" => 33.00,"total" => 726.00),
"1" => Array("id" => 2,"quote_id" => 1,"position" => 2,"type" => "dwdw","number" => 22,"cost" => 22.00,"total" => 484.00));



var_dump(array_merge($content,array_unique($empty)));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => int 1
      'quote_id' => int 1
      'position' => int 1
      'type' => string 'dwdwdw' (length=6)
      'number' => int 22
      'cost' => float 33
      'total' => float 726
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => int 2
      'quote_id' => int 1
      'position' => int 2
      'type' => string 'dwdw' (length=4)
      'number' => int 22
      'cost' => float 22
      'total' => float 484
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => null
      'quote_id' => null
      'position' => null
      'type' => null
      'number' => null
      'cost' => null
      'total' => null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 $i=0;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $youArray[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
 $youArray[$i]['quote_id']=$row['quote_id'];
 //remaining values
 $i++;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had done somethign similar using a foreach loop